# Parse Server (aws-mongolab) Images Not Retrieving

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, parse-server

I started to use parse server with mongolab and AWS, everything works fine, but the images are not retrieved, I read somewhere that I need to set the "fileKey". I tried to add it to AWS console as in the image below. However it is still not working? Am I doing anything wrong, do I need to add it also to the appDelegate in my IOS Swift project? How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

saner,

UPDATE: As of 12pm PST March 9, 2016, the "[Parse Server on AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxCD57GZLM2JR/How-to-set-up-Parse-Server-on-AWS-using-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk)" solution INCLUDES the FILE_KEY Environment Property and is parsed by the application. So, no need to go through this process below but it is still useful for any other application updates you'll need to make in the future. /END Update

Just to clarify your issue, I’m assuming you are unable to access any of your “legacy” Parse Files (uploaded to your application prior to the migration) and you’re **not** having issues accessing newly uploaded files? If so, read on.

**Issue**: Unable to retrieving any files that were uploaded to your application prior to migrating to Parse Server on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

**Problem**: The migrated Parse Sever is unable to retrieve legacy files (hosted on Parse-owned S3 bucket) due to an incorrect path missing your Parse File Key. E.g. If you perform a simple GET for an object associated with a file, you’ll getting the following:

"url":http://files.parsetfss.com/invalid-file-key/tfss-0a209bb7-8497-4e4f-8cdf-a5d4190a48c4-myTwins.jpg

The `/invalid-file-key/` URL parameter is the missing ingredient and was put in place by the Parse Server as the default placeholder if a File Key is not provided. After making the suggested changes below, the same request will return the correct url with the `/invalid-file-key/` replaced with your /actual File Key/.

To learn more about Parse Files, see my [other Stack Overflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403791/parse-migration-to-heroku-aws-regarding-the-image/35420258#35420258) here regarding pre/post migration Parse Files.

**Solution**: Setting the FILE_KEY Property Name within the EB Environment Property as you did is correct but, unfortunately, you’ll need to make an additional change to the index.js file on the Parse Server to actually read the File Key property. There’s two ways to update your Parse Server application. Elastic Beanstalk Console or using the Elastic Beanstalk CLI (EB CLI). Both solutions are provided below:

**Adding your Parse Files “File Key” to your existing Parse Server on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.**

> (Console) Update Application Version using the AWS Elastic Beanstalk
>   Management Console:

This solution involves downloading the existing EB Application Version (as a .zip archive) of your Parse Server, modifying the index.js file locally, zipping it back up, and finally uploading the changes to the same Application Versions page as a new version of the application.
Download and edit current Parse Server EB Application Version:

- Open the Elastic Beanstalk console.
- From the region list, select the region that includes the application that you want to work with.
- From the Elastic Beanstalk console applications page, click the name of the application to which you want to add a new application version.
- In the navigation pane, click Application Versions.

  [image]
- Click on the  .zip file link under Source to download the Application locally.
- Unzip the application
- Edit the index.js file in root of the application and add the line highlighted in yellow. 
  [image]
- Save the index.js file.
- Zip up the application (***NOTE*** Only zip up the root objects within the unzipped folder, not the folder containing the objects.)

**Upload** the new version of your Parse Server application:

- From the Application Versions EB page for your Parse Server application, click Upload.
- Provide a Version Label and Description, select your updated .zip application and click **Upload**.
- This will upload a “new version” of your application while the previous version is still running.

**Deploy** the new version of your Parse Server application:

- Select the newly uploaded version and click Deploy.
- Select your environment from the dropdown and click Deploy.

**Final Step**:
Add the FILE_KEY environment property as shown in your screenshot. Click Apply.

If you run into any issues with this solution, please follow these EB deployment instructions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.deployment.html

> (CLI) Using the Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Interface ([EB CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html)):

This solution uses the EB CLI to download, edit, and deploy a new version of your Parse Server Application.

- mkdir tmp-app-folder
- cd tmp-app-folder
- eb init (select region, app, and environment running the code)
- eb labs download (Downloads the code from the EB environment)
- Make necessary changes to the index.js file
- eb deploy (app rebuilds)
- eb setenv FILE_KEY= (app rebuilds again)
  **Done.**

**Obtaining your Parse File Key**:
The Parse hosted File Key can be obtained from the Parse.com Console.
Log into Parse.com, select your app and copy the "File key" under App Settings > Security & Keys. 
Note: Parse makes the "File Key" available in the "beta" dashboard only.

I know this seems like a long-winded detail of instructions for a simple solution but it should also help other Parse developers needing to update their Parse Server application in their Elastic Beanstalk environment in the future. For example, if you wanted to [store files post-migration to your own S3 bucket](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Storing-Files-in-AWS-S3)

Answer (score 1):

it Looks that you have missed fileKey in index.js file.

Get File key from parse dashboard

[image]

GO to you index.js file of parse server and set filekey value.

var api = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
      appId: 'xxx',
      clientKey: 'xxx',
      masterKey: 'xxx',
      fileKey: 'xxx'
});